# How to remove symbol from string in perl (underscore)

Tags: perl, printing

Hi I tried to remove _ (underscore) from words in perl.
I have some things in table in database and there is word with underscores and i want better print only for style... :)

```
my $result = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
my $randid = rand @$result; 
my $row    = $result->[ $randid ];
if($row ne ''){

     print "- @$row\n";
     print "<BR />";

     } else { 
          print "";
 }
```

OUTPUT NOW:

```
word_and_word
next_word
and_next_word
```

I WANT TO:

```
word and word
next word
and next word
```

Comment: A very easy replace can be done using tr/_//. It replaces a list of chars against the chars of the same index from the second argument, e.g. tr/abc/ABC/ to change case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translate `_` char to space char in all places for `$word`,

```
$word =~ tr|_| |;
```

In your case that would be

```
for my $row (@$result) { $row->[0] =~ tr|_| |; }
```

Comment: Can't modify array dereference in transliteration (tr///)

Comment: i dont have variable word... only row

Comment: didn't use `$row` as it's not completely clear is it array ref or plain string => `@$row` in code above.

Comment: if `$row` is array reference as it seems, `if($row ne '')` should read as `if(@$row)`, and string translation could only be applied to array elements. Ie, for all elements of `@$row` that would be `tr|_| | for @$row`

Comment: Dobro, to je onda dvodimenzionalno polje, ili?

Comment: its array from select query

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30571/discussion-between-tomas-kocian-and-mpapec)